# Замена строки в подстроке JavaScript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, node.js, парсер

Есть строка:

```
let formula = 'A+B*(ABS(B-A))'
```

И есть объект:

```
let replace_func = {
    A: 'C+5',
    B: 'D-2'
}
```

Необходимо сделать замену переменных в строке 'formula' на элементы 'replace_func' по ключам, так чтобы получилось:

```
let result = '(C+5)+(D-2)*(ABS((D-2)-(C+5)))'
```

Чтобы избежать замены в названии функции *ABS()*, было решено использовать регулярку:

```
let replace_regx = new RegExp('[\/\*\-\+\(]?' + cur_key + '[\/\*\-\+\)]?')
formula = formula.replace(replace_regx, replace_func[cur_key])
```

Но по регулярке заменяется не только название переменой, но и знаки перед и после нее (напр. вместо **'A'** берется **'-A)'**)

Как можно решить данную проблему? В регулярках не силен, поэтому прошу помощи)

Comment: переменный только однобуквенные?

Comment: @Grundy, только однобуквенные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как переменная в данном случая является словом из одной буквы, можно воспользоваться [`\b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#boundaries) - означающим границу слова.

В этом случае регулярное выражение примет вид:

```
/\b\w\b/g
```

При использовании этого выражения в методе replace, в функцию-обработчик будет передаваться отдельно стоящая буква, которая и будет возможной переменной для замены.

Возвращать из функции обработчика можно либо значение соответствующее замене, либо, если переменная отсутствует в списке замен, само совпавшее значение.

И общий вызов станет более общим.

```js
let formula = 'A+B*(ABS(B-A))'
let replace_func = {
  A: 'C+5',
  B: 'D-2'
}
console.log(formula);
let result = formula.replace(/\b\w\b/g, $0 => `(${replace_func[$0] || $0})`);
console.log(result);
```